# Images don't get loaded when source maps are enabled

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, source-maps, css-loader

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './1.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.png$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap']},
            {test: /\.sass$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']},
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'template.ejs',
        }),
    ],
};
```

`template.ejs`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

`1.js`:

```
require('./1.css');
require('./1.sass');
```

`1.sass`:

```
div
    width: 100px
    height: 100px
    margin: auto
    background: url(1.png) no-repeat
```

`1.css`:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url(1.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Then

```
$ npm i
$ rm -rf dist/* && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

And open `http://example.com/dist` in browser. Both images are not displayed. But if you remove `sourceMap` query param from css loaders, it'll work out.

What's the matter? How to remedy it?

Comment: You should leave a comment here noting that this is meant as a canonical self answers post, as well as what situation you observed that in your opinion necessitated this pair of question and answer. This way, no one will be confused when reading your question as to the intent of what the answer should contain.

Comment: @TravisJ Indeed, I answered my post myself. And maybe the question is canonical. As for the situation, I don't really understand what's not clear. I wanted to have source maps, but when I enabled them, images disappeared. And there are two questions at the end: 1) what's causing the matter, and 2) how to fix it. Please elaborate.

Comment: I have found it beneficial to leave a self explanatory comment on the question, when you are posting both the question and answer as a pair, just so that if people skim past your post (tl;dr;) they can also have a reference to what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the doc has to say:

[`style-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/blob/v0.13.1/README.md):

> Note about source maps support and assets referenced with url: when style loader is used with ?sourceMap option, the CSS modules will be generated as Blobs, so relative paths don't work (they would be relative to chrome:blob or chrome:devtools). In order for assets to maintain correct paths setting output.publicPath property of webpack configuration must be set, so that absolute paths are generated.

[`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/blob/v0.26.0/README.md):

> They are not enabled by default because they expose a runtime overhead and increase in bundle size (JS SourceMap do not). In addition to that relative paths are buggy and you need to use an absolute public path which include the server url.

And here are [some](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/issues/55) [related](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/232) [issues](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/194).

So, when you enable source maps, css files are added as blobs. And relative paths stop working. My guess is it's `style-loader`'s doing. No offense here, maybe there's no better way.

And one way to deal with it is... disable source maps :) The second one, to specify absolute url in `output.publicPath`. And by absolute I mean the one with a domain name. And the third option is... to extract css code into separate files, with `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

Here's the `webpack.config.js` with code resolving the issue commented out. Choose the option which suits you best:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './1.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        // publicPath: 'http://example.com/dist/',   // (2)
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.png$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap']},
            // {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')},   // (3)
            {test: /\.sass$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']},
            // {test: /\.sass$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')},   // (3)
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'template.ejs',
        }),
        // new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),   // (3)
    ],
};
```